# How binary/UUID columns can be mapped?

Tags: cube.js

The column is defined as `binary(16)` in the database and the values are `UUID`.

The database is MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `binary` field as `string` by formatting it using `HEX` function. Typical Cube.js schema in this case will look like:

```
cube(`Users`, {
  // ...

  dimensions: {
    companyId: {
      sql: `HEX(${CUBE}.company_uuid)`,
      type: `string`
    }
  }
});
```

Filter for `Users.companyId` field in this case will look like

```
{
  // ...,
  filters: [{
    dimension: "Users.companyId",
    operator: "equals",
    values: ["0123456789ABCDED0123456789ABCDEF"]
  }]
}
```

If you have an index on this `binary` column you probably want to hint MySQL query planner with `FILTER_PARAMS` so it can be used:

```
cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE ${FILTER_PARAMS.Users.companyId.filter(
    v => `company_uuid = UNHEX(${v})`
  )}`,
  // ...

  dimensions: {
    companyId: {
      sql: `HEX(${CUBE}.company_uuid)`,
      type: `string`
    }
  }
});
```

Learn more on `FILTER_PARAMS` here: https://cube.dev/docs/cube#context-variables-filter-params.